# Defining a hotkey in Google documents using Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-docs

I am trying to define a new hotkey in Google documents. I am trying to use a Chrome extension, the problem is when the document area is active, the browser can't listen to the event fired. Here's the extension code.

Edit: Here's the manifest file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Cool Extension",
  "version": "0.1",
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
      "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.js", "content.js"]
  }
],
"permissions": [
  "tabs"
]
}
```

Here's the content.js file

```
    var map = {17: false};

$('body').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode in map) {
        map[e.keyCode] = true;
        if (map[17]) {
console.log("Hi");
        }
    }
}).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode in map) {
        map[e.keyCode] = false;
    }
});
```

The above extension works fine on any website. When you press ctrl, it will log "Hi". The extension works fine on any website and in Google Docs itself if the upper bar that contains the menus is active. It logs Hi when the ctrl key is pressed. But when the document area is active, the code doesn't fire.

Background: I am thinking of having the ability to use Chrome extensions with Google Apps Script to define custom hotkeys, just faced the problem of not firing events in the active document area.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to **guess** at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: Alright, edited. Thank you for your feedback and let me know if I have to provide anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is not visible, Docs editing content is within an iframe. Your content_script is not loading on iframes.

You can enable this by adding to new rules to your [content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in manifest.json:

```
    "all_frames": true,
    "match_about_blank": true
```

The first allows your code to load on frames. The second one allows to load on empty pages (and frames). Together with your current manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Cool Extension",
  "version": "0.1",
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["jquery.js", "content.js"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "match_about_blank": true
  }
],
"permissions": [
  "tabs"
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [chrome.commands](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) API instead of jQuery.